# Part of a page to stay loaded throughout the website

Tags: ajax

I was wondering if it was possible to have one element only loaded once upon visiting my website.

In other words, I have a `<div>` which contains a bunch of different spritely backgrounds, and I was wondering if I could only have that single `<div>` load once, and then, each time an end-user loads a different page, that `<div>` stays the same.

The effect I would like to achieve is to not have the animation start over.

How hard is this to implement, and how exactly do I do this?  Is this too much of a hassle to quickly implement?  Also, I believe this has something to do with Ajax, is that right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Also, I believe this has something to do with Ajax, is that right?

You can update your entire site except your `div` "with ajax", i.e. without refreshing the page. This implies, that your website must be a kind of javascript application. If it isn't already, you'll need to rewrite some (or more) parts.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I like Gus' idea better, just because it's a little more compatible with what I have right now, and takes no rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

A more simple solution may be to use your server side code to determine if the page request is the first, or a subsequent request, and show a static background for these subsequent requests.

This can be done in a few lines in most server-side languages. Which are you using?

Comment: Cool, that sounds great!  I'm using ASP and ASP.NET actually

Comment: I would suggest using a session variable to store when a user first visits the site. I don't know ASP all that well, but it looks like you can just set
<% Session("seen-animation") = True %>
and before this, check for this being set and either display the animation or the static image.

Comment: Well, what I mean is, I want the animation to be left off from the end-user's previous page.  Say, you navigate the first page long enough to see the underground animation, and then you navigate to the "Shop!" page, I would like for the animation to continue from where it had left off.

Comment: Can you tell your animation to start at different points, from within the HTML? If so, you could get a rough idea of how long the animation has been playing for by storing the date and time the animation was started in a session variable. Then you could check the time difference on the second request and serve the relevant part of the animation.  If starting the animation halfway through is not a go, then it would have to be Ajax I think.